# Selecting an entire paragraph by just matching a string

Tags: python, regex, nltk, text-mining

Suppose I have two paragraphs while reading a file:

```
'Baa, baa, black sheep, have you any wool?
Yes sir, yes sir, three bags full!
One for the master
One for the dame'

'Mary had a little lamb,
its fleece was white as snow;
And everywhere that Mary went,
the lamb was sure to go.'
```

Is there any code (using regular expressions or something) that, if I search `'lamb'`, will select the entire second paragraph?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the paragraphs are all in a single string, something like this should work:

```
def select_paragraph(text, word, delimiter='\n'):
    return [p for p in text.split(delimiter) if word in p]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will select a paragraph containing `lamb`:

```
([^\']*(?=lamb)[^\']*)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xY8jY9/1)

Here's python code:

```
import re
data = """
'Baa, baa, black sheep, have you any wool?
Yes sir, yes sir, three bags full!
One for the master
One for the dame'

'Mary had a little lamb,
its fleece was white as snow;
And everywhere that Mary went,
the lamb was sure to go.'
"""

match = re.search('([^\']*(?=lamb)[^\']*)',data)
print(match.group())
```

`Output:`

```
Mary had a little lamb,
its fleece was white as snow;
And everywhere that Mary went,
the lamb was sure to go.
```